# Can speech be added to a receipt card?

Tags: c#, botframework

I am using the bot framework technology in one of my projects and the receipt card suits my needs perfectly. I wanted to know if it is possible to provide a speech text to the output displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the receipt card is an attachment to a message, it doesn't have a property for speech.  However, you can set the .Speak property of the message itself.  Something like this:

```
var message = context.MakeMessage();
message.Speak = "Here is your receipt.";

var attachment = GetReceiptCard();
message.Attachments.Add(attachment);

await context.PostAsync(message);
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. However, I believe that the message.Speak is not supported for the "Cortana" channel is which is what I am working with.

Comment: Here is a link to the docs that mention Cortana specifically: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/tutorials/bot-skills/teach-your-bot-to-speak#add-speech-in-the-botbuilder-net-sdk

Comment: I just tried it out and it works perfectly/ Thanks @Eric